# Getting Error With GROUP BY when Converting Query to Dynamic SQL

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to convert the following query to dynamic SQL to allow for variations:

```
UPDATE T
SET SumCount = J.SUM
FROM #temp T
    JOIN (SELECT Count_99221 + COUNT_99222 + Count_99223 [SUM], t2.userID
          FROM #temp t2
          GROUP BY t2.userID, Count_99221 + COUNT_99222 + Count_99223
          ) J ON T.userID = J.UserID
```

This is what I have for the Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql3 nvarchar(2000) = 
'UPDATE T ' + 
'SET SumCount = J.SumOfColumns ' + 
'FROM #temp T ' + 
'JOIN (SELECT ' + @columnSumString + ' [SumOfColumns], t2.userID ' + 
'FROM #temp t2 ' + 
'GROUP BY t2.userID, ' + @columnSumString +
' ) J ON T.userID = J.UserID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql3
```

I am receiving the following error only when I run the query as Dynamic SQL:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not
>   an outer reference.

Can somebody help explain why this is happening? I am new to Dynamic SQL so I'm not privy to any limitations for running queries this way.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

The variable @columnString is a string made by concatenating several other column names, created in the following way:

```
DECLARE @Cursor Cursor
DECLARE @code varchar(20)
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @cptCursor = CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@UserInput,CHAR(44))

OPEN @cptCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @cptCursor INTO @ID, @code
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE @colName varchar(50) = 'Count_' + cast(@code as varchar(10))
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(50) = 'ALTER TABLE #temp ADD ' + @colName + ' int'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

--Code that adds values to each column that is created.....

SET @columnSumString = @colName + ' + ' + @columnSumString
--SET @columnSumString = @code + ' + ' + @columnSumString

FETCH NEXT FROM @cptCursor INTO @ID, @code
END
CLOSE @Cursor
DEALLOCATE @Cursor

SET @columnSumString = SUBSTRING(@columnSumString,1,LEN(@columnSumString)-2)
SELECT @columnSumString
```

The user input is a comma separated string. "Count_99221 + COUNT_99222 + Count_99223" is just one example of columns created from the user input "99221, 99222, 99223".

I also realized I was concatenating the @code variable into @columnSumString instead of @colName. Now when I run the query I don't get the error (even though I don't understand how the above error message relates to that mistake) but every value of SumCount is NULL.

Comment: What is in parameter ColumnSumString ? From the error, it sounds like it is not a column name. Give us an example of what columnSumString is.

Comment: If you replace the EXEC line with PRINT @sql3, copy the result and run it in a separate query, does it work?

Comment: Why don't you print the sql command and see it for ur self ?

Comment: SUM is reserved word. please change name of your alias

Comment: @DancingFool I have edited the answer to show how the variable columnString is made. Also, I tried replacing EXEC with PRINT and it resulted in all NULL values in the SUMCOUNT Column

Comment: @JoeTaras Ok, I have done so. Is there any reason this would cause errors for the query?

Comment: The error about GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you must re-write your query as follow:

```
UPDATE #temp
SET SumCount =
    (SELECT Count_99221 + COUNT_99222 + Count_99223
    FROM #temp t2
    WHERE t2.userID = #temp.userID)
```

So the dynamic SQL will become:

```
DECLARE @columnString varchar(200)
SET @columnString = Count_99221 + COUNT_99222 + Count_99223

DECLARE @sql3 nvarchar(2000) = 
N'UPDATE #temp ' + 
'SET SumCount = (SELECT ' + @columnString +
    ' FROM #temp t2 WHERE t2.userID = #temp.userID)'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql3
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @W.Harr: More efficient. I don't LIKE UPDATE JOIN. Finally on Sql Server you can't use alias on UPDATE table

Comment: I tried replacing what I had in the query with your suggested edit and got the following error message: "Incorrect Syntax Near 't2'". I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Count_99221 and other are existing fields?

Comment: Update my answer (add a space before FROM)

Comment: Your solution is working great. If you have time, could you help me pinpoint what in my original solution was causing NULL values once I converted the UPDATE to Dynamic SQL? I would like to know so I don't run into this problem again. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @W.Harr: If I've accomplished to your aim, please accept my answer. In which part have you null?